# How to delete an element from a mapping?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mapping, struct

I have a mapping like this:

```
struct data {  
   string name;  
   string nickname;  
}

mapping(address => data) public user;
```

What is the correct way to delete one element from the variable user? Do I only have to call `delete(user[address])`

or

do I also have to delete `user[address].name` and `user[address].nickname`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, `delete user[someAddress];` will work with structs that do not contain a mapping.

For this question, because `name` and `nickname` are not mappings, they will be deleted (set to zero) automatically: there is no need to do something like "delete user[someAddress].name".

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#delete

> if you delete a struct, it will reset all members that are not mappings and also recurse into the members unless they are mappings

Caveat:

> delete has no effect on whole mappings (as the keys of mappings may be arbitrary and are generally unknown)

Comment: What will happen with the data in user[someaddres].name and user[someaddress].nickname of the example above, when I do delete user[someAddress]? Will they be deleted as well or do I have to delete them before I do delete user[someAddress]?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added to the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Does this mean "delete" doesn't free storage space, to delete and set to zero are two different things, no?

Comment: @Jaime "delete" in a smart contract is just setting values to zero.  Recovering disk space is an implementation detail and up to the node: it might see a zero and do "pruning", but it might not.

Comment: Deleting elements from an array and re-arranging it to eliminate holes does save gas in the form of gas refund (an amount is subtracted from your gas cost). Is there not something similar with mappings?

Comment: @Qwerty Refunds have been reduced in [EIP-3529](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3529).